# How to export class libraries in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, export

In Eclipse when I implement a class library and I'm ready to deploy, I usually export and package it into a JAR file that later you can just add to the build path in another project. Is there an equivalent feature in Visual Studio? Is there a proper way to "publish" a class library and package it into a dll file to later add as a reference in another project? Or do you just usually go and dig for it in the bin folder yourself?

Comment: change the output path? change `debug` to `release`? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @HighCore For example, when you are going to deploy an ASP.NET MVC project, you don't just go ahead and dig for the assemblies in the bin folder. You properly right click and "Publish" into a web server or folder in your file system. Is there a similar thing for libraries?

Comment: why would you need that? a solitary assembly is not a thing that you can "publish" per se. You can change the output path in the `release` configuration and then select this configuration when ready to "publish"

Comment: I thought there was a more official way to export assemblies, not just copy and paste from the bin folder.

Comment: copy and paste where? where would you copy a single assembly to?

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes Did you read my answer? Use a build event.

Comment: @HighCore anywhere; post it online for other developers to use for example.

Comment: @yasmanillanes that's what [NuGet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) is for.

Comment: @tnw I saw your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most VS projects compile into a DLL. If you want your DLL to be "published" to some particular location when you build, you can use [build events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165412.aspx) which can also package up your dll (you could call a batch script, for example, that takes care of that for you).

> Is there a proper way to "publish" a class library and package it into a dll file to later add as a reference in another project? Or do you just usually go and dig for it in the bin folder yourself?

Sure, just add the `bin\debug\yourdll.dll` or `bin\release\yourdll.dll` as a reference in your other project, or otherwise to the location you moved it to in your build event. No need to go digging for it every time.

Comment: I understand what you suggest. I was just expecting a more official approach, but if just getting it from the bin folder is what Microsoft expects me to do, then so be it.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes Unsure what kind of answer you're looking for. What is an "official approach"?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that assemblies generated in the `bin` folder when you build your project were not just half baked assemblies intended to be used only for debugging purposes of some sort. I guess I was just overcomplicating things.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes The assembly built into the `debug` directory will function just as well as the one in the `release` directory if you add it as a reference, but obviously it's recommended to use the `release` dll if you are not debugging.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the output type to 'release' or 'Debug'.
2. Go to Build, Build Solution (Or f5)
3. Navigate to: The Solution Bin folder for release or debug.

   3a. You can quickly navigate to the solution folder by right clicking the solution in the
     'Solution explorer' and selecting 'Open folder in File Explorer'.
   The compiled DLL file will be in that directory. (bin\release or bin\debug)

Comment: how to i add resource as well with the dll?